# What regular expression in grep searches for strings of three same letters in a row?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have a text file and I am using the grep command with a regular expression to get only the lines which contain three same successive letters, e.g.: aaa bbb ccc ddd

What regular expression do I need to use in : grep "**regex**" filename

Comment: what does `grep aaa` not get you? Or do you want: `grep '\([[:alpha:]]\)\1\1'`?

Comment: As mikeserv wrote, or in general `grep '\([[:alpha:]]\)\1\{2\}'`.

Comment: did you want to match this `aaaa` line also? Because this contains three consecutive a's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf 'aabbbccddd\nabcdef' | grep '\([a-z]\)\1\1'
```

Output:
    aa**bbb**cc**ddd**

The bracket pair `\(\)` makes a backreference, which is referenced by `\1`

Comment: bracket pair called capturing group  used to capture all the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group. Here the pattern present inside the capturing group is `[a-z]`. `\1` means we are back-referencing to the group index 1 (ie, we are referring the characters stored inside the group index 1)

Answer (score 1):

using grep

`echo -e "aaa bbb ccc ddd\n hello world"|egrep  '([a-z])\1{2}'`

`([a-z])` remembers the first letter found.

`\1{2}` check to see if the first letter found is repeated two more times.

Comment: Standard ERE don't support back-references, `grep '\([a-z]\)\1\{2\}'` (BRE) would be POSIX/portable.

Comment: I am aware of this..but I believe the newer versions of egrep do support this..for example try `echo " heeeloo"|egrep -o --color '([a-z])\1{2}'`..this will output the pattern `eee`,that is, the same output of  `grep '\([a-z]\)\1\{2\}'`